# How to change the Selectable ControlStyle of a button to make it stop recieving focus

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm making a pong game and I have a couple of buttons to do different things, my movement keys are W & S , Up & Down. The problem is the up and down arrows are setting focus to the buttons and not providing proper movement. I know making them picture box's would fix this but I really want to use a button control as they look better. The forms KeyPreview is also already set to true.

```
Public Enum Direction { None, Up, Down };
Direction leftDir;

If (e.keycode == keys.Up) leftDir = Direction.Up;
If (e.keycode == keys.Down) leftDir = Direction.Down;
```

This doesn’t receive the conditional though as the key press is passed over by the focus set of the buttons

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Sorry I didn’t include it I didn’t know what would be useful to see

Comment: Any minimal code that can duplicate the problem for us.

Comment: I just have a couple of buttons and a key down/up tracking W & S and Up & Down. Sorry It won’t let me edit my question so I can’t add the actually code

Comment: `Sorry It won’t let me edit my question`  Just click on the edit link.  Post code as text with a four space indent for formatting.

Comment: It’s a Windows forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custom button and apply `SetStyle` method.

```
public ButtonX : Button
{
   public ButtonX
   {
      SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
   }
}
```

Or by changing focus to another control. For example if you have label inside your form, after you're doing something with your button just call `label.Focus();`.

Comment: will that change the control style of that button or all the buttons?

Comment: Create custom button class as I already mentioned. Replace your old buttons with this custom button.